# Underhanging section headings and continuous indentation of text following section heading

Tags: sectioning, margins, indentation, titlesec

I'm looking to replicate a style of indentation found in the MtG Comprehensive rules as shown below. Specifically the underhanging of section headings where the numbering sticks out a little but the start of the heading isn't inline with the underhanging text. And the continuous indentation of all text following the section (i.e. when you create a section/subsection etc. the following text will use the same margin until you move onto the next section) ideally without having to surround them in an environment (i.e just set the margin using the section function somehow?)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

My current attempt using the titlesec package

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

% Chapter
\titleformat{\chapter}
    [hang]                          % paragraph shape
    {\normalfont\bfseries\large}    % format applied to label+text
    {\thechapter}                   % label
    {1em}                           % horizontal separation between label and title body
    {}                              % before the title body
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0em}{0em}{1em}

% Section
\titleformat{\section}
    [hang]
    {\normalfont\normalsize}
    {\thesection}
    {0.5em}
    {}
\titlespacing{\section}{0em}{1em}{1em}

% Sub-section
\titleformat{\subsection}
    [hang]
    {\normalfont\normalsize}
    {\thesubsection}
    {0.5em}
    {}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{3em}{1em}{1em}
```

```
\chapter{Lipsum}

\section{Test 1} 
    \subsection{\lipsum[1]}

\section{Test 2}
    \subsection{\lipsum[2]}
    \lipsum[3]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Had to resort to using enumerate instead of subsections and subsubsections etc. but using `enumitem` package you can fine tune the layout of the enumerate environment to produce essentially an identical layout.

```latex
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{
    label=\thesection.\arabic*.,
    align=left,         % Align left side of labels
    leftmargin=!,       % Keep margins as is
    labelindent=1em,    % Indent start of label (and following paragraphs)
    itemindent=1em     % Indent hanging paragraphs
}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{
    label=\thesection.\arabic{enumi}\alph*,
    align=left,
    leftmargin=!,
    itemindent=1em
}
```

And then for the content:

```latex
\chapter{Lipsum}

\section{Test 1} 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}

\section{Test 2}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \lipsum[2] \\
        \lipsum[3]
    \end{enumerate}
```

[image]